# NInject ConstructorArgument with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, ninject, ninject-2

Is there any way to create an instance of ConstructorArgument using lambda expression instead of hardcoded string to define the name of the property?

Something like this:

```
var validator = Ioc.Kernel.Get<Validators.Security.UserGroupValidator>(new ConstructorArgument( x => x.ValidationDictionary, new ValidationDictionary())
```

In my case, the ValidationDictionary is not the same in many places and for this reason, I can't use a Provider.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ToConstructor binding like

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/

```
   Bind<UsergroupValidator>().ToConstructor(_ => new Usergroupvalidator(new ValidationDictionary());
```

Or even let the validation dictionary be injected as defined in the blogpost.

Comment: Like I said, this is exactly what I can't do because the instance of ValidationDictionary is different in each place where I use the validator.